# Command runs in ISE but not as ps1 in Console

Tags: powershell

I found numerous threads and went through them but none of them really adressed my issue. I try to keep it short.

```
New-PSDrive –Name "G" –PSProvider FileSystem –Root "\\dom\dfs\dom-loc-Share" –Persist
```

It works perfectly fine if I run it from the ISE. 
It works fine when I copy paste it to the console.
It does not work if I try running the ps1 in the console.

- I restarted the ISE
- I checked and both run in Single Threaded Apartment
- Executionpolicy is unrestricted
- I run both as administrator

Can you please help me?

Comment: Do you get an error from `New-PSDrive`?

Comment: No, if I run manually in console:

`    C:\temp> New-PSDrive -Description "Gruppen-Laufwerk" -Name "G" -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\domain\dfs\domain-location-Share" -
Persist `

it works fine

Comment: Yes, I got that, but when you run the script, you dont't get an error, it just doesn't mount the G: volume, is that correctly understood?

Comment: Sorry, yes @MathiasR.Jessen it just shows the normal output: **Name Used (GB) Free (GB) Provider Root CurrentLocation**
_G 44,80 52,52 FileSystem \\domain\dfs\domain-location-Share –_
But it won't create the PSDrive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-Scope Global`, for more information visit this technet article:

> about_Scopes https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849.aspx
>
> [...]
>   Windows PowerShell protects access to variables, aliases, functions,
>   and **Windows PowerShell drives (PSDrives)** by limiting where they can be
>   read and changed. By enforcing a few simple rules for scope, Windows
>   PowerShell  helps to ensure that you do not inadvertently change an
>   item that should not be changed. [...]

```
New-PSDrive –Name "G" –PSProvider FileSystem –Root "\\dom\dfs\dom-loc-Share" –Persist -Scope Global
```

Comment: Yes! That's what was missing. Now it is working fine - thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

How are you checking whether the G drive's mapped?

If you run the below in your script, that'll show you via `Get-PSDrive` if the drive's been created:

```
if(Get-PSDrive | ?{$_.Name -eq "G"}) {
    'Removing G'
    Remove-PSDrive "G"
}


'Adding G'
New-PSDrive –Name "G" –PSProvider FileSystem –Root "\\ukcconas2edc\ax_docs" –Persist


'Does G Exist?'
Get-PSDrive | ?{$_.Name -eq "G"}
```

If you're just checking through Windows Explorer, I think some funny things happen with caching there.
After running the script, click on `Computer`, then on the right pane (where the drives are listed) right click and select `Refresh`; hopefully the G drive will now show.

Also, if you have a different powershell console and you're checking by running `push-location g:` or `get-psdrive`, if the session you're using to check for the drive was created before that drive was created, it won't list it.  I assume this is due to caching in powershell / perhaps is deliberate to avoid scripts run in parallel from interfering with one another?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I only posted part of the script to keep the answer to the point. Thank you for your input though, I will use it to improve my version.